# Populate ListView from SQLite database on android

Tags: android, xml, sqlite, listview, android-listview

I have this database and I need to populate this `ListView` with the information.

I already have a method on my DBHandler class which is:

```
 public List<Appointment> getAppointments(){
            List<Appointment> appointmentList = new ArrayList<Appointment>();
            String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_APP;//query to search appointment by title
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                do{
                    Appointment appointment = new Appointment();
                    appointment.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                    appointment.setDate(cursor.getString(1));
                    appointment.setTitle(cursor.getString(2));
                    appointment.setTime(cursor.getString(3));
                    appointment.setDetails(cursor.getString(4));

                    appointmentList.add(appointment);
                } while(cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            return appointmentList;
        }
```

And now I need to populate the list on my DeleteAppointment class:

```
   package com.example.calendar;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class DeleteAppointment extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    Appointment app;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.delete);
        Button delete = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
        Button deleteAll = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_deleteAll);
        ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.apptList);
        DBHandler db = new DBHandler(this);
        String[] columns = new String[]{app._date, app._title, app._time, app._details};
        int[] viewIDs = new int[]{R.id.date, R.id.name, R.id.time, R.id.details};
        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) db.getAppointments();
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.item, cursor, columns, viewIDs, 0);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.btn_delete:
            finish();
        break;
        }

    }

}
```

And the xml file for the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView android:id="@+id/apptList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>

        <TableLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_delete"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/deleteDialog"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_deleteAll"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/deleteAll"/>

            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

The item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/details"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the Appointment class:

```
package com.example.calendar;

import java.sql.Date;

public class Appointment {

    //variables(that are the attributes of the database table)
    int _id;
    String _title;
    String _time;
    String _details;
    String _date;

    //empty constructor to add for the update method in the DBHandler
    public Appointment(){

    }

    public Appointment(int id, String date, String title, String time, String details){

        this._id = id;
        this._date = date;
        this._title = title;
        this._time = time;
        this._details = details;

    }

    public Appointment(String date, String title, String time, String details){

        this._date = date;
        this._title = title;
        this._time = time;
        this._details = details;

    }

    //----------GET/SET METHODS BELOW-----------

    //--------ID---------

    public int getID(){
        return this._id;
    }

    public void setID(int id){
        this._id = id;
    }

    //-------DATE-------

    public String getDate(){
        return this._date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date){
        this._date = date;
    }

    //-----TITLE---------

    public String getTitle(){
        return this._title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title){
        this._title = title;
    }

    //------TIME-------

    public String getTime(){
        return this._time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time){
        this._time = time;
    }

    //------DETAILS--------

    public String getDetails(){
        return this._details;
    }

    public void setDetails(String details){
        this._details = details;
    }

}
```

How can I populate this list in a simple way?

Please help.

Comment: simple way? use SimpleCursorAdapter

Comment: and? is it working or not?

Comment: @pskink I'm close but not quite there

Comment: it doesnt help much, whats wrong?

Comment: given the answer below, I need to populate the list but the row has to have all the attri ute in one big string. How do I do that?

Comment: String[] columns should contain column names from your cursor, so if you do "select name, age from ...." you should put "name", "age" in columns[], with SCA you dont need Appointment class and you donr need to iterate over the cursor,you  just create a Cursor, create SCA and attach it to a ListView

Comment: @pskink could you please post an answer for this? I tried it twice yesterday but it kept giving me errors. Maybe I was doing something wrong

Comment: see for example http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/

Comment: @pskink I don't have an URI? Any suggestions on how to use it?

Comment: they need an Uri to get a Cursor, you have the Cursor (cursor = db.rawQuery) so you dont need an Uri

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this after `ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.apptList);`

```
ArrayAdapter<Appointment> mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Appointment>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, getAppointments());
list.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
```

P.S. You should override the method toString() in `Appointment` to control what get's displayed in the list view.

Add:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return _title;
}
```

to your appointment class to make it like this:

```
public class Appointment {

    //variables(that are the attributes of the database table)
    int _id;
    String _title;
    String _time;
    String _details;
    String _date;

    //empty constructor to add for the update method in the DBHandler
    public Appointment(){

    }

    public Appointment(int id, String date, String title, String time, String details){

        this._id = id;
        this._date = date;
        this._title = title;
        this._time = time;
        this._details = details;

    }

    public Appointment(String date, String title, String time, String details){

        this._date = date;
        this._title = title;
        this._time = time;
        this._details = details;

    }

    //----------GET/SET METHODS BELOW-----------

    //--------ID---------

    public int getID(){
        return this._id;
    }

    public void setID(int id){
        this._id = id;
    }

    //-------DATE-------

    public String getDate(){
        return this._date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date){
        this._date = date;
    }

    //-----TITLE---------

    public String getTitle(){
        return this._title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title){
        this._title = title;
    }

    //------TIME-------

    public String getTime(){
        return this._time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time){
        this._time = time;
    }

    //------DETAILS--------

    public String getDetails(){
        return this._details;
    }

    public void setDetails(String details){
        this._details = details;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return _title;
    }

}
```

Comment: it's not working. Instead of showing the appointments, it shows com.example.calendar.Appointment@417f1980

Comment: You should override the method toString() in `Appointment` to control what get's displayed in the list view, Wrote that 20 minutes ago ;)

Comment: override the method toString() or the public list itself?

Comment: What ever toString returns will be displayed in the list view, so if you want to display name + time then by all means return name + " " + time;

Comment: I recon you will need a more customized view, in the future for that you can search for "listview example" or click here http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: so like @Override
 public String getName(){
  return this._name;
 }   ?

Comment: the problem is that whenever i override a method it gives me an error in the appointment class

Comment: @jPratas dont use ArrayAdapter, use SimpleCursorAtapter

Comment: @jPratas Updated, Sorry I had to sleep it was so late last night.

Comment: No problem. Is that the only method that has to be overridden?

Comment: @Shereef I need it to show all the elements.  Do I need to make the same to the other columns?

Comment: `return _title + " " + _details;` just add them to the output of `toString`………

but if you want to style them then there is no simple way of doing it, but it's doable and relatively easy, but not as simple as this.